# Issues loading TLS from a string instead of a file

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin, grpc

The error I get:

```
io.grpc.ManagedChannelRegistry$ProviderNotFoundException: io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelProvider: Unable to load private key: Neither RSA nor EC worked
```

I am trying to load pass the certificate as a string instead of reading a file, because it is dynamic. In order to establish a gRPC connection.

```
class GrpcModule(
        private val certificateRoot: String,
        private val certificateStr: String,
        private val privateKeyStr: String,
) {
    val channel: ManagedChannel by lazy {

        val pk: InputStream = privateKeyStr.byteInputStream()
        val cu: InputStream = certificateStr.byteInputStream()
        val cr: InputStream = certificateRoot.byteInputStream()

        val credentials =
                TlsChannelCredentials.newBuilder()
                        .keyManager(
                            pk,
                            cu
                        )
                        .trustManager(cr)
                        .build()

        Grpc.newChannelBuilder("localhost:50001", credentials)
                .executor(Dispatchers.IO.asExecutor())
                .build()
    }
    private val stub = ReceivingGrpcKt.ReceivingCoroutineStub(channel)

    suspend fun checkId(id: String) =
            try {
                val request = checkRequest { this.id = id }
                val response = stub.check(request)
                Log.d("Grpc", "Success --- $response")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d("Grpc", "Error --- $e")
            }

    fun close() {
        channel.shutdownNow()
    }
}
```

And I'll be calling it from a ReactNative module, like so:

```
class Grpc(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext) : ReactContextBaseJavaModule(reactContext) {

    override fun getName() = "Grpc"

    @ReactMethod
    fun test() {

        var g =
                GrpcModule(
                """
                     -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
                     -----END CERTIFICATE-----
                """.trimIndent(),
                    """
                    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
                    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
                """.trimIndent(),
                    """
                    -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
                    -----END PRIVATE KEY-----
                """.trimIndent(),
                )

        Log.d("Grpc", "--- $g")

        runBlocking {
            g.checkId("222")
        }

        g.close()
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here and how can I fix this?

Is this even the right way to go about it?

Comment: There should have been a "Caused by" exception with potentially more info. Most likely the key is not of a supported type. If you have the openssl command, `openssl pkey -text_pub -noout -in YOUR.KEY` might help answer which key type it is (the longer blobs of data aren't likely important).

Comment: @EricAnderson you mean this `ASN1 OID: prime256v1` `NIST CURVE: P-256`? Do not have Caused by...

Comment: Usually Java software expects certificates as part of a `java.security.KeyStore`. You can create a Java KeyStore instance at run-time and insert the loaded certificate into it.

Comment: I can create such a key with `openssl genpkey -algorithm EC -out out.pem -pkeyopt ec_paramgen_curve:P-256 -pkeyopt ec_param_enc:named_curve`. On Java 8 and OkHttp, that works fine. I think this is Android-specific. Are you using the Dynamic Security Provider or Conscrypt? https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md#tls-on-android

Comment: @EricAnderson I've tried `Security.insertProviderAt(Conscrypt.newProvider(), 1);`, still getting the same error. It's just that I'm reading the certificate data through react native and passing it as a string to the kotlin backend so that I can establish a grpc connection. However I cannot seem to get the certificate to be read.